# Matplotlib "pick_event" not working in embedded graph with FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to handle some events to perform user interactions with embedded subplots into a Tkinter frame. Like in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)

Works fine with "key_press_event" and "button_press_event", but does not work with "pick_event".

I modified that example from the link, just adding the following piece of code after the `mpl_connect` calling:

```
def on_button_press(event):
    print('you pressed mouse button')

canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_button_press)

def on_pick(event):
    print('you picked:',event.artist)

canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
```

Why "pick_event" doesn't work into embedded graphs? And how do get it to work?

My configurations detailed:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.5 (conda version)
- Matplotlib 1.5.3 installed via pip

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I solved it...

Most events we just need to use `mpl_connect` method to the magic happen. My mistake is that I didn't notice that we need to say explictly that our plot is "pickable" putting a argument `picker=True` to only triggers the event if clicked exacly into the artist, and `picker=x` where `x` is an integer that is the pixel tolerance for the trigger. So beyond the changes I inserted for pick in the question, we should replace

`a.plot(t, s)` for `a.plot(t, s,picker=True)` or `a.plot(t, s,picker=10)`, e.g.

Comment: I got it to work with `axis = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1,picker=True)`