# matplotlib pick_event in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

Is there any way to use `'pick_event'` while using Tkinter back-end? I can use tk canvas to show my plots but couldn't find any document that handles pick_evet within tkinter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936869/matplotlib-pick-event-not-working-in-embedded-graph-with-figurecanvastkagg?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: `'pick_event'` is independent on the backend (as long as it's interactive). So it's not really clear what you're asking here. In case you experience a problem, please provide a [mcve] including the undesired behaviour and/or full error traceback.